# Help with calculating distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Distance from ottawa to chicago is 1440km and distance from Chicago to new york is 1120km and distance from Ottawa to New York is 995km. What is distance from halfway between ottawa and Chicago to New York? What is distance at 720km point to New York?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Presumably in this problem you are expected to pretend that the region is locally flat, flat enough to ignore the curvature of the earth.  Try drawing yourself a picture of the triangle(s) in question and label the lengths of each side.  Use what you have learned about triangles to continue (for example the pythagorean theorem).

Comment: For what it is worth, all of this flavor about cities and all of the exact numbers appearing are mostly irrelevant.  You should have been able to do this just as easily had the numbers been smaller like $4,6,8$ or if they were left as unknowns like $a,b,c$

Comment: Looks like we need geographical knowledge too, so we can determine whether we are talking triangles or straight lines.

Comment: $\frac{1440}{6400}=0.225$, $2 \arcsin(0.225/2)=0.2255\approx 0.225\cdot 1.002$. Within relative error $0.2$% one can consider triangle as flat with the same sides. Then this is standard geometry problem. One need to find cosine of some angle using cosine rule, then one need to use cosine rule again to find required distance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: OCNY]

The first step of solving a problem like this is to draw a diagram similar to the one given above. There are several method to determine the distance $MN$, where $M$ marks the halfway point between Ottawa and Chicago. One such option is described in the comment of @IvanKaznacheyeu. Using the following formula is another option.
$$MN=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2NO^2+2NC^2-OC^2}$$